# Ecma6 Class Event handler

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I was wondering how I could add a Eventhandler in a Ecma6 class. The following example works, but I would like the event handlers in the class itself.

Here the code for the Class

```
class Bot {
constructor(username,password,shared_secret,identity_secret,bot_number) {
    this._username = username;
    this._password = password;
    this._shared_secret = shared_secret;
    this._identity_secret = identity_secret;
    this._bot_number = bot_number;
    this._logged = false;
    this._client = new SteamUser();
    this._manager = new TradeOfferManager({
        "steam": this._client, 
        "domain": "xxxxxxx", 
        "language": "en", 
        "pollInterval": "3000",
        "cancelTime": "1800000" 
    })
    this._community = new SteamCommunity();

}

get botNumber() {
    return this._bot_number;
}

get client() {
    return this._client;
}

get manager() {
    return this._manager;
}

set logged(logged) {
    this._logged = logged;
}

login() {
    console.log("In Login Request for Bot: "+this._bot_number)
    this._client.logOn({
        "accountName": this._username,
        "password": this._password,
        "twoFactorCode": SteamTotp.getAuthCode(this._shared_secret)
    })
}

setWebCookies(sessionID,cookies,botNumber,manager) {
    manager.setCookies(cookies, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            process.exit(1); // Fatal error since we couldn't get our API key
            return;
        }
        console.log("Got API key: " + manager.apiKey+" for Bot Number: "+botNumber);
    });
    this._community.setCookies(cookies);
}
```

And here where I use the class and add the Event Handler outside of the class

```
    bot1.login();

bot1.client.on('webSession', function (sessionID, cookies) {
    bot1.setWebCookies(sessionID,cookies,bot1.botNumber,bot1.manager);
});

bot1.client.on('loggedOn', function () {
    console.log("Bot "+bot1.botNumber+" successfully logged in!");
    bot1.logged(true);
});
```

And again I would like to have that event handler in the Class itself.

Comment: Sure, just put it in a method of `bot1`? What's the problem, have you tried that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setWebCookies() {
  this.client.on('webSession', (sessionID, cookies) => {
      this.setWebCookies(sessionID,cookies,this.botNumber,this.manager);
  });
}
```

Is there anything wrong with using something like this in your class? Note that I made your callback an arrow function so the `this` context is retained. You can also use bind, if you want.